# Fetch an active branch on a new machine via Gitlab GUI

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

[image]

I worked on some code on Machine A. Now, it is committed to **the respective branch but it is NOT merged into master** yet. Now, I want to be able to clone that branch (is the term clone the branch even correct?) on Machine B and use it there.

I know that CLI can probably take me via the route git fetch or something but I need to do this via Gitlab.com GUI.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply push the `Clone` button: that will clone the full repository onto your local machine.

Once cloned, you can go there and type:

```
git switch yourBranch
```

Since `origin/yourBranch` will have been cloned as part of the full repository history, that switch command will create automatically a local `yourBranch` tracking `origin/yourBranch`.

---

Don't forget, you can even do some changes directly on the Web with the [Web IDE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/) (which can [switch branches as well](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/#switching-branches))

See [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#create-and-switch-branches-in-the-web-ide-beta) (March 2023)

> ### Create and switch branches in the Web IDE Beta
>
> When you open the Web IDE Beta from a repository or merge request, the currently selected branch is used by default.
>
> You can create a new branch with your changes or, if you’re not on a protected branch, commit to the current branch.
>
> Starting with GitLab 15.10, you can now *also* create a new branch any time while making changes or switch branches in the Web IDE Beta.
> This way, you can boost your productivity by not having to close the Web IDE Beta to switch contexts.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_10/create-web-ide-manage-branches.png -- Create and switch branches in the Web IDE Beta]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide_beta/#switch-branches) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-web-ide/-/issues/72).

Comment: Yes, the Web IDE way is what I can't find any documentation for. I managed to do it using the CLI. Any pointers there?

Comment: @ankitrana_ https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/#switching-branches is the documentation for the Web IDE: what is missing in that documentation?

Comment: If I was to use the Web IDE to switch a branch does that replicate it on my local /User/Documents/Github/ActiveBranch too or not?
I've never used this but it seems like a one stop place where you can edit code, commit to branches and merge intp master from gitlab.com based IDE itself. however, I want the code from a non-merged branch to appear in my local hard-drive copy.

Comment: @ankitrana_ WebIDe means online only: no files on your computer.

Comment: @ankitrana_ "however, I want the code from a non-merged branch to appear in my local hard-drive copy. " Then clone and switch, as mentioned in my answer: the unmerged branch will be on your computer.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to stick with the command line for now. It helped.